# Java 8 Streams Filter a list based on a condition

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to extract a filtered list on top of the original list based on some condition. I am using backport version of Java 8 and am not pretty sure how to do this.I get the Set from ccarReport.getCcarReportWorkflowInstances() call. I need to iterate and filter this set based on a condition match( I am comparing the date attribute in each object with the request date being passed. Below is the code

```
  Set<CcarReportWorkflowInstance> ccarReportWorkflowInstanceSet = ccarReport.getCcarReportWorkflowInstances();
  List<CcarReportWorkflowInstance> ccarReportWorkflowInstances = StreamSupport.stream(ccarReportWorkflowInstanceSet).filter(ccarReportWorkflowInstance -> DateUtils.isSameDay(cobDate, ccarReportWorkflowInstance.getCobDate()));
```

The routine which is doing the job

```
  public List<CcarRepWfInstDTO> fetchReportInstances(Long reportId, Date cobDate) {
    List<CcarRepWfInstDTO> ccarRepWfInstDTOs = null;
    CcarReport ccarReport = validateInstanceSearchParams(reportId, cobDate);
    Set<CcarReportWorkflowInstance> ccarReportWorkflowInstanceSet = ccarReport.getCcarReportWorkflowInstances();
    List<CcarReportWorkflowInstance> ccarReportWorkflowInstances = StreamSupport.stream(ccarReportWorkflowInstanceSet).filter(ccarReportWorkflowInstance -> DateUtils.isSameDay(cobDate, ccarReportWorkflowInstance.getCobDate()));
    ccarRepWfInstDTOs = ccarRepWfInstMapper.ccarRepWfInstsToCcarRepWfInstDTOs(ccarReportWorkflowInstances);
    return ccarRepWfInstDTOs;
}
```

Error I get when I tried to use streams.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understood what you are trying to do, you can replace your method body with a single line :

```
return 
  validateInstanceSearchParams(reportId, cobDate).getCcarReportWorkflowInstances()
                                                 .stream()
                                                 .filter(c -> DateUtils.isSameDay(cobDate, c.getCobDate()))
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. You can obtain a Stream from the Set by using the `stream()` method. No need for `StreamSupport.stream()`.
2. After filtering the Stream, you should `collect` it into the output `List`.
3. I'd use shorter variable and method names. Your code is painful to read.

Comment: its throwing a compile time error saying it cannot return a custom object but only of Type<T>

Comment: @Balaji On which method call do you get this error?

Comment: I have attached the image containing the error as part of question.Please have a look

Comment: I am using StreamSupport.stream() because the code will be deployed in Java 7 environment and development is done using Java 8 using backport supporting JARs.Hence the usage

Comment: @Balaji: what’s the problem in simply writing the name of the method? That’s less effort than creating a screenshot.

Comment: @Balaji: Well, that’s exactly the problem. You are mixing two entirely different APIs. Java 8’s standard collector can’t implement your custom collector interface. Of course, it’s unfortunate that both have the same simple name. Look at the beginning of the package names in the error message…

Comment: @Holger I wanted to present the actual error message so that nothing is missed in what I am trying to convey